# entity framework multiple columns mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to implement database structure in which there are common fields i put them in a separate abstract class but i want to know if 3 classes are inheriting from same abstract class and 2 have same property name so, by default entity framework will add a numeric followed by property name in database. Is there any way to implement this separately. I've studied complex types and searched over internet but couldn't find any flexible solution. I'm sharing my code, please guide me

```
public abstract class GenericImpression
    {
        [Key]
        public int ImpressionId { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset ReportingDate { get; set; }
    }


public class Impression : GenericImpression
    {       
        public string InventorySource { get; set; }
        public string Media { get; set; }
    }

public class Impression21 : GenericImpression
        {       
            public string InventorySource { get; set; }
        }
```

Now, EF will add one table with InventorySource1 and InventorySource Column.

Answer (score 0):

Use OfType<>.
Example:

```
_context.GenericImpressions.ofType<Impression21>().ToList()
```